# How can we use the dependency parser output to text embeddings? or Feature extractions from text?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp

Knowing the dependencies between various parts of the sentence
can add some information to existing knowledge from raw texts, Now the question is how can we use this to get a good feature representation, which can be fed into classifier such as logistic regression, sim etc. just as TfIdfvectorizer gives us a vector representation, for text documents. I'd like to know what different methods are there to get these kind of representation using output of  dependency parser?

Comment: interesting idea. for what purpose?

Comment: @arturomp For classification of texts